# Qiskit Transpiler Error: Unknown Operation Type

Tags: qiskit, transpile

I am trying to use the reset function and recieving the following error:

```
Failed - TranspilerError: "Unknown operation type for DAGOpNode(op=Instruction(name='reset', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qargs=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(7, 'q'), 0),), cargs=())
```

I have confirmed that reset is in the instruction set of the backend I am using (imb_nairobi), and it seems like the command works fine with the simulators so I am not sure what the issue is. My circuit makes it all the way through the queue without issue and the graph of the transpiled circuit looks correct (attached), but I do not get my results. I am pretty new to Qiskit/coding in general so I apologize if I am missing something obvious. I have tried using reset by setting each qubit with a loop as well as all together, such as in the snippet here:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(7)
cr = ClassicalRegister(7*shots)
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr) 

for i in range(shots):
    # reset qubit state
    circ.reset(qr)
    seven_q_GHZ(qr, circ)  # A command I made for building seven qubit GHZ state
```

[image: Transpiled Circuit]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
As per request, my full code. Qiskit versions are:

```
  Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
qiskit                    0.44.1                   pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-aer                0.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ibm-provider       0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ibm-runtime        0.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-terra              0.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
```

```
# Initialize the account
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum")
backend = service.backend("ibm_nairobi")
sampler = Sampler(backend=backend)

# Setup
shots = 2  # Number of times to collect measurement
qr = QuantumRegister(7)
cr = ClassicalRegister(7*shots)
circ = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)  # Circuit for register of 7 qubits and 7 classical bits

# Experiment
list_bases = {}  # List for recording measurement basis
for i in range(shots):
    # reset qubit state
    circ.reset(qr)
    seven_q_GHZ(qr, circ)

    # Randomize Measurement Basis
    for j in range(7):
        list_bases[i*7 + j] = random_basis(circ, qr, j)
        circ.measure(qr[j], cr[i*7 + j])

    circ.barrier(qr)  # Forces an order to operations

job = sampler.run(circ, shots=1)
print(f">>> Job ID: {job.job_id()}")
print(f">>> Job Status: {job.status()}")
```

Commands called defined as:

````
def random_basis(circuit, q_register, qubit):
    """
    Rotates a qubit such that, when measured, it is done so in a 'random' basis.

    :param circuit: The circuit we are acting on
    :param q_register: The quantum register of the circuit
    :param qubit: The qubit we are acting on
    :return: The random number representing basis
    """
    rand_int = random.randint(0, 2)
    if rand_int > 0:
        if rand_int == 1:
            circuit.sdg(q_register[qubit])
        circuit.h(q_register[qubit])
    return rand_int


def seven_q_GHZ(qr, circuit):
    """
    Creates a 7-qubit GHZ state.

    :param circuit: Circuit being acted on
    :param qr: Quantum register of at least 7 qubits
    :return: none
    """

    circuit.h(qr[0])  # Hadamard gate on qubit0 -> sets superposition (|0> + |1>)/sqrt(2)
    circuit.cx(qr[0], qr[1])  # C-NOT gate between qubit0 and qubit1
    circuit.cx(qr[0], qr[2])  # C-NOT gate between qubit0 and qubit2
    circuit.cx(qr[2], qr[3])  # C-NOT gate between qubit2 and qubit3
    circuit.cx(qr[0], qr[4])  # C-NOT gate between qubit0 and qubit4
    circuit.cx(qr[4], qr[5])  # C-NOT gate between qubit4 and qubit5
    circuit.cx(qr[4], qr[6])  # C-NOT gate between qubit4 and qubit6

    circuit.barrier(range(7))  # Aids in circuit grouping, guides optimization

```
````

Comment: Can you put your full code (in particular the way you transpile your circuit with all defined variables and the way you send it to the backend) in your post? Also, please provide your Qiskit version, it will be simpler for us to help you that way

Comment: Hello Tristan! I am not sure if I am replying correctly, but I have edited my question to address your comments.

Comment: Try to add barrier just after `circ.reset(qr)`

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a barrier after the reset did not solve the issue.

Comment: @lightly Perfect!